# Implementing backpressure in custom RxJava pipeline

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to write complex entity-emitting system with XML parser underneath it, and can't get a proper grasp on backpressure. Currently I have following interface (which my parser implements):

```java
public interface Reader<T> {
    void read(T chunk, Recorder recorder) throws FatalException;

    default Flowable<Object> toFlowable(Flowable<T> input) {
        return input.flatMap(chunk -> {
            Recorder recorder = new Accumulator();
            read(chunk, recorder);
            var combination = Stream.concat(recorder.values.stream(), recorder.errors.stream().map(ErrorEvent::new))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return Flowable.fromIterable(combination);
        }, false, 128, 1); // note the buffer size of one
    }
}
```

Where chunk is a single XML tag in implementation, so my parser may record 0..1 items at one call. I want to completely pause reading until subscriber requests new item.

I test it this way:

```java
var reader = new XmlReader(handlers);
// collection of XML tags in form of
// <root><child>content</child><child>content</child>...
var source = Flowable.fromIterable(standardDocument());
var stream = reader.toFlowable(source);
stream.subscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<>() {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object o) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {}
});

verify(root, times(1)).getChildHandler("child"); // means only one <child> tag was encountered
```

However, the test fails with following assertion error:

```
entityHandler.getChildHandler("child");
Wanted 1 time:
-> at redacted.reader.xml.XmlReaderTest.respectsBackpressure(XmlReaderTest.java:156)
But was 18 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at redacted.reader.xml.XmlReader.lambda$handleStart$1(XmlReader.java:52)
```

"18 times" is max number no matter how many times my fake document will repeat `<child>` tag, so it feels like there's a buffer. However, as you can see in code above, I'm setting buffer to size of one. What did I miss and how do i make my parser pause until new item is requested by subscriber?

Comment: You parse the entire chunk and give the whole thing to RxJava to reemit.

Comment: @akarnokd i'm new to Rx* libraries. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList())` this will realize the entire stream upfront before you hand it to RxJava.

Comment: @akarnokd for that specific implementation it is guaranteed that there's one element at max.

Comment: I can't tell more without seeing all relevant code. If there is an undesired invocation, place a breakpoint on that XmlReader.java:52 and check the stacktrace for operators.